# method with name .apply not work in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this method:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import com.xx.model.preferences.keys.BooleanPref
import com.xx.model.preferences.keys.StringPref
import javax.inject.Inject

override fun saveBoolean(pref: BooleanPref, value: Boolean) {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(pref.key, value).apply()
}
```

and my compiler says:

> e: /model/preferences/PreferencesManager.kt: (24, 68): No value passed for parameter 'block'

but my apply method is from **SharedPreference** not from std lib of Kotlin.

How to solve this? thx

Comment: Are you using apply{} instead of apply()  by any chance ?

Comment: I've got similar code in my projects and it resolves the apply function correctly, so it should be doable. What version of Kotlin and Android Studio are you running?

Comment: this is only in this project, in others works.

Comment: Does (24, 68) correspond to the snippet you've posted? Can't see `parameter 'block'`

Comment: What happens when you hold `Control` and click on `apply`? The source of which function does it show? It would be also nice to see your `import`s section.

Comment: I'd suspect Jitendra's hunch is correct. For SharedPreferences.Editor, commit() performs a similar function. What happens when you change apply() to commit()?

Comment: @PiotrK show two methods. I replace apply to commit, but this problems is very very strange.

Comment: @RafaelF. Do you have an explicit  import for `apply` from `SharedPreference`? Please show us your imports.

Comment: @PiotrK the post was updated with imports

Comment: @RafaelF.  Unfortunately I'm still missing some context. Ideally I'd ask you to prepare a SSCCE (sscce.org), so that it's possible to download a compete project and reproduce the problem locally. If I were you, I'd just take your project, optionally (if you want to keep your source closed) delete all pieces not relevant to the problem but still so that the problem is reproducible, and share it with us here. Then we can tinker with it locally.